# Android Studio firebase database wait for read before adding new values

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database in which I store users and I want to check if a user exists before adding a new one so I don't overwrite.

I have a function that goes through database records and returns a boolean value if it finds or doesn't find the user.

```
public boolean checkUserExists(final String emailAddress, final String emailDomain){
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users");

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot mydata : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                User user = mydata.getValue(User.class);

                if (user.getEmailAddress().equals(emailAddress) &&
                        user.getEmailDomain().equals(emailDomain)){
                    userExists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return userExists;
}
```

The way I am currently trying to do the check is like this:

```
if (!(registerRepo.checkUserExists(emailAddress, emailDomain))){
                User user = new User(firsName, lastName, emailAddress, emailDomain);
                registerRepo.writeUser(user);
            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "User exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
```

The problem is that it doesn't wait for the read and goes ahead and creates a new record (I'm using push so it creates the same record under a new push ID). I've seen that firebase has such a thing called transaction handler and I think that is what I need to use but the documentation didn't help me and I've looked at others asking sort-of the same question here but couldn't figure out a solution so please, if you can explain how to do it and not redirect me to other question I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase requests are asynchronous.

So you need to add a callback in your `checkUserExists` if you want to do some code after getting the result from database.

**For example :**

```
public interface OnCheckUserExist {
    void exist();
    void notExist();
}

registerRepo.checkUserExists(emailAddress, emailDomain, new OnCheckUserExist(){
   @Override
   public void exist(){
       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "User exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
       toast.show();
   }
   @Override
   public void notExist(){
       User user = new User(firsName, lastName, emailAddress, emailDomain);
       registerRepo.writeUser(user);
   }
})


public void checkUserExists(final String emailAddress, final String emailDomain, OnCheckUserExist onCheckUserExist){
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users");
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        boolean userExist;

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot mydata : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                User user = mydata.getValue(User.class);

                if (user.getEmailAddress().equals(emailAddress) &&
                        user.getEmailDomain().equals(emailDomain)){
                    onCheckUserExist.exist();
                    userExist = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!userExist){
              onCheckUserExist.notExist();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is that callback? I know that for regular asyncTasks is onPostExecute. Is it the same here? Where do I add it?

Comment: I tried this method and it says that .exist() and .notExist() are non-static methods and they cannot be referenced from a static content. If I make exist() and notExist() static it says that 'Extensions methods are not supported at this language level'. Help please

Comment: You have to create the **interface** OnCheckUserExist for create a listener.

Comment: I did create it in RegisterRepo class. Is that the wrong place?

Comment: No it should work... You need to add an anonymous class for creating a listener or implements directly this interface.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! Can I ask what you did because from syntax PoV looks almost identical with what I changed when you told me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your code inside onDataChange like this

```
public boolean checkUserExists(final String emailAddress, final String emailDomain){
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Users");

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot mydata : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                User user = mydata.getValue(User.class);

                if (user.getEmailAddress().equals(emailAddress) &&
                        user.getEmailDomain().equals(emailDomain)){
                    userExists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (userExists) {
                User user = new User(firsName, lastName, emailAddress, emailDomain);
                registerRepo.writeUser(user);
            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "User exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return userExists;
}
```

Though I would suggest you to refactor this one by creating separate functions. :)

Comment: I want to have them separated using the 4 layer principle and doing it this way it would mean to combine the Data Access Layer with the Application Logic Layer.